# Semmle QL: TaintTracking hasFlow() Problem with Sources that taint their Arguments

Tags: c, semmle-ql

I want to do TaintTracking with functions that taint their arguments with userinput. Example:

```
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin); // buf is tainted
[...]
n = strlen(buf); // tainted argument to strlen
[...]
memcpy(somewhere, buf, n) // tainted call to memcpy
```

Semmle should be able to spot this with a Query like the following (just with fgets->strlen as example). I am borrowing code from SecurityOptions:

```
import cpp
import semmle.code.cpp.dataflow.TaintTracking

class IsTaintedArg extends string {
  IsTaintedArg() { this = "IsTaintedArg" }
  predicate userInputArgument(FunctionCall functionCall, int arg) {
    exists(string fname |
      functionCall.getTarget().hasGlobalName(fname) and
      exists(functionCall.getArgument(arg)) and (fname = "fgets" and arg = 0) // argument 0 of fgets is tainted
    )
  }

  predicate isUserInput(Expr expr, string cause) {
    exists(FunctionCall fc, int i |
      this.userInputArgument(fc, i) and
      expr = fc.getArgument(i) and
      cause = fc.getTarget().getName()
    )
  }
}

class TaintedFormatConfig extends TaintTracking::Configuration {
  TaintedFormatConfig() { this = "TaintedFormatConfig" }
  override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node source) {
    exists (IsTaintedArg opts |
      opts.isUserInput(source.asExpr(), _)
    )
  }
  override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) { 
    exists (FunctionCall fc | sink.asExpr() = fc.getArgument(0) and fc.getTarget().hasName("strlen")) // give me all calls that land in strlen's first argument
  }
}

from TaintedFormatConfig cfg, DataFlow::Node source, DataFlow::Node sink
where cfg.hasFlow(source, sink)
select sink, source
```

Yet it does not look like it is working.

When I just Query `cfg.isSource()` or `cfg.isSink()` however, both source and sink are recognized. But `hasFlow()` still returns nothing - although a path should definitely exist.

- I am using libssh2 to test my findings, the example flow exists [here](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/blob/452517d96c2a636fa0e2f31cfa8b463886de7611/example/sftp.c#L77).
- My Query to test around is [here](https://lgtm.com/query/4924205385826766133/).

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong in the Query above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing bit is in `isSource`, where the taint tracking starts from the 0'th argument to `fgets`. Using `asExpr` will describe the flow from that argument *into* `fgets`. What we want is the flow *out of* fgets through that argument. You'll get that by replacing `asExpr` with `asDefiningArgument`.

[Here](https://lgtm.com/query/4743547486378660516/) is a link to the results for your query where I've used both `asExpr` and `asDefiningArgument` in `isSource`. This means that if you extend `isUserInput` in the future, its expressions will be considered sources both as their value and as output arguments.

The new version of the query has 8 results, and some of them are hard to understand when you only see the source and the sink because they can be in different files. I've made a cleaned-up version of the query that

- generates path explanations between sources and sinks (`@kind path-problem`),
- removes the `IsTaintedArg` class wrapping of the helper predicates,
- removes a few unused parameters and checks, and
- adds the call to `asDefiningArgument`.

Here is the full query:

```
/**
 * @kind path-problem
 * @id taint-to-strlen
 */
import cpp
import semmle.code.cpp.dataflow.DataFlow
import DataFlow::PathGraph

predicate userInputArgument(FunctionCall functionCall, int arg) {
  functionCall.getTarget().hasGlobalName("fgets") and
  arg = 0 // argument 0 of fgets is tainted
}

predicate isUserInput(Expr expr) {
  exists(FunctionCall fc, int i |
    userInputArgument(fc, i) and
    expr = fc.getArgument(i)
  )
}

class TaintedFormatConfig extends DataFlow::Configuration {
  TaintedFormatConfig() { this = "TaintedFormatConfig" }
  override predicate isSource(DataFlow::Node source) {
    isUserInput(source.asExpr())
    or
    isUserInput(source.asDefiningArgument())
  }
  override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) { 
    exists (FunctionCall fc | sink.asExpr() = fc.getArgument(0) and fc.getTarget().hasName("strlen"))
  }
}

from TaintedFormatConfig cfg, DataFlow::PathNode source, DataFlow::PathNode sink
where cfg.hasFlowPath(source, sink)
select sink, source, sink, "Taint from fgets call in " + source.getNode().getFunction().getFile().getBaseName()
```

You can see the results at https://lgtm.com/query/4800800615370766111/.

Comment: There are a few more differences between the query you posted in-line and my cleaned-up version because I based my version on the query in [https://lgtm.com/query/4924205385826766133/](the link) you put in the original post.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work fine now! 
However, using this Query I am now running into problems where I want the sink to be some kind of Assignment. E.g. to detect calls like `free(tainted)` -> `tainted = NULL`, I would do the following:
`override predicate isSink(DataFlow::Node sink) { 
    exists (AssignExpr e | e.getRValue().getValue().toInt() = 0 and e.getLValue() = sink.asExpr())
  }` with `userInputArgument` set to `free` of course. This also does not detect the Paths although I feel like it should. Is the sink wrongly defined now?

Comment: @themee There won't be data flow out of `free` or into the LHS of an assignment. I don't think your problem is a data flow problem in the Semmle QL meaning of the word. Perhaps the library you're looking for is `semmle.code.cpp.controlflow.LocalScopeVariableReachability`.